# Kusto parse operator on a multi-line string for a non-greedy match of either of two strings

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I need to match all **multi-line content** from the start of **msg** up to the **first** match of **either** of:   **--- End of** or **at**. Msg is a typical messy C# async stack trace. I can't seem to use the parse operator to do it.

I'm trying to use the parse operator b/c I don't know how to specify **flags=Us** on an extract function call. If I knew how to do that, I probably wouldn't try the parse operator, since it is easier to put in the match conditions that I happen to need.

So 2 questions:

1. Can I use extract() to specify the equivalent of **parse kind-regex flags=Us ...** since I need a non-greedy match.
2. If not and I have to use the parse operator for non-greedy matching (since I want to match the least greedy occurrence of the strings below), how do you either chain 2 parse operators like I am trying to do below, or do what I am trying to do in one parse line.

```
    // figure out how to use parse operator, or maybe extract for a non-greedy "(...|...)" match
    datatable(msg:string) [
    \`\`\`Error: ArgumentNullException: foo
      at Microsoft.XXX
      at Microsoft.YYY
      at Microsoft.ZZZ\`\`\`,
    \`\`\`Error: ArgumentNullException: bar
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
      at Microsoft.XXX
      at Microsoft.YYY\`\`\`
    ]
    | parse kind=regex flags=Us msg with msg1 "--- End of"
    | parse kind=regex flags=Us msg1 with msg2 "  at "
    | project msg2
```

```
    // I want it to output:
    Error: ArgumentNullException: foo
    Error: ArgumentNullException: bar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `extract()` function, you can include `(?flags)` in the regex.

For example, for case insensitivity (the flag `i`), you'll add the `(?i)` in `@"(?i)([a-z]+)"`

See: https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax

Comment: Perfect! just what I needed, since extract() is much easier to do things like non-greedy stops on multiple phrases, whichever comes first.